# change plesk subscription expire date via API

Tags: plesk-onyx

how can i prolong plesk subscription expire date via XML RPC or REST?
in the following code i can create subrcription, but i want a way to change the expiration date after creation.

```
<webspace>
    <add>
      <gen_setup>
        <name>{domainName}</name>
        <owner-login>{username}</owner-login>
        <ip_address>1.1.1.1</ip_address>
      </gen_setup>
      <hosting>
        <vrt_hst>
         <property>
            <name>ftp_login</name>
            <value>ftp_{ftpUsername}</value>
          </property>
          <property>
            <name>ftp_password</name>
            <value>{pass}</value>
          </property>
          <ip_address>1.1.1.1</ip_address>
        </vrt_hst>
      </hosting>
      <plan-name>{plan}</plan-name>
    </add>
  </webspace>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get subscription properties which include experation date in [UNIXTIME](https://www.epochconverter.com/) using the following request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<packet version="1.6.7.0">         
 <webspace>
  <get>
   <filter>
    <name>example.com</name>
   </filter>
   <dataset>
    <limits/>
   </dataset>
  </get>
 </webspace>
</packet>
```

To set the expiration date, use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<packet version="1.6.7.0">         
 <webspace>
  <set>
   <filter>
    <name>example.com</name>
   </filter>
   <values>
    <limits>
     <limit>
      <name>expiration</name>
      <value>1600000000</value>
     </limit>
    </limits>
   </values>
  </set>
 </webspace>
</packet>
```

Where `example.com` is a subscription name, `1600000000` - expiration date in UNIXTIME.